# Customizing OOB web parts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I've done a lot of digging and still have yet to find a good solution to customizing out of the box web parts using SharePoint 2013.  I basically just want to change the appearance of the discussion board web part but there is no easy way to apply CSS to it without effecting everything else on the site that uses those classes (since I can't apply ID's to the html and the ID's supplied are specific down to a GUID).  The best way I've found so far is to use jQuery which sounds like a horrific method to maintain.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Discussion board is yet another List View so you can apply custom XSL to it. This is maybe the recomended SharePoint like way, but dealing with XSL is time consuming and if your XSL file has even one error in it, the SharePoint would reject it and reverse the dafault list view so this costs patience and precision.

One you have completed your custom XSL you can apply it by accessing the webpart properties (in Edit mode) -> Miscellaneous -> XSL Link (where you specify where your XSL file is located on the server)

Comment: This does look like the solution for List Views like the Discussion Board but is there any way to hook up XSL to other web parts like the Content Editor?  I don't see the miscellaneous section with XSL link in there.

Comment: Since the List View is XML driven webpart you can apply XSL styles , but this is not the case for the Content Editor. The Content Editor webpart is ment to be HTML/JavaScript holder so Its purpose is to be HTML driven holder of information and if not filled with HTML content, basically you have nothing to style within the web part :). I hope I was clear, if you have any questions please do not hesitate :)